# gps and ultrasonic code for esp8266mod board

Tags: c++, arduino

I use esp8266mod to programing  code for gps and ultrasonic
the code work correctly when run every code alone but when combine the code gps not working but the ultrasonic give distance . if there someone can help me to solve this problem

code for gps and code of ultrasonic

here is my code:

```
#include <TinyGPS++.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <HttpClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#define echoPin 16 // attach pin D2 Arduino to pin Echo of HC-SR04
#define trigPin 4 //attach pin D4 Arduino to pin Trig of HC-SR04
// defines variables
long duration; // variable for the duration of sound wave travel
int distance; // variable for the distance measurement
int RXPin = 13;
int TXPin = 0;
int GPSBaud = 9600;
// Create a TinyGPS++ object
TinyGPSPlus gps;
SoftwareSerial gpsSerial(RXPin, TXPin);
                      
long  cm, inches;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
 
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an OUTPUT
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an INPUT
  Serial.println("Ultrasonic Sensor HC-SR04 Test"); // print some text in Serial Monitor
  Serial.println("with WeMos ");
 gpsSerial.begin(GPSBaud);
 
  delay(2000);
 
}
void loop()
{
 currentMillis = millis();
 
 digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  // Sets the trigPin HIGH (ACTIVE) for 10 microseconds
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  
       
  // Calculating the distance
 distance= duration*0.034/2; // Speed of sound wave divided by 2 (go and back)
           

    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Distance: ");
  Serial.print(distance);
      
    while (gpsSerial.available() > 0)
    if (gps.encode(gpsSerial.read()))
      displayInfo();
   if (millis() > 5000 && gps.charsProcessed() < 10)
  {
    Serial.println("No GPS detected");
    while(true);
  }
  
 
}
}
long microsecondsToCentimeters(long microseconds)
{
return microseconds / 29 / 2;
}
void displayInfo()
{
  if (gps.location.isValid())
  {
    Serial.print("Latitude: ");
    Serial.println(gps.location.lat(), 6);
    Serial.print("Longitude: ");
    Serial.println(gps.location.lng(), 6);
    Serial.print("Altitude: ");
    Serial.println(gps.altitude.meters());
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Location: Not Available");
  }
  
     Serial.println();
 
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bORfg.jpg)